# Workbook Prompts for Changes Upon Closing When no Changes Were Made

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have an Excel file that runs some ActiveX components. The downside is that it asks to save each time I close the file, even when I didn't make any changes.
I've tried adding the following code to the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. It still asks me to save the file when I try to close it without making changes.

Any help?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ActiveWorkbook.Save, without "d"?

Comment: Check [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/213428/how-to-suppress-save-changes-prompt-when-you-close-a-workbook-in-excel) for some ideas to try.

Comment: @Basher - No, `Save` will save it, `Saved` will set the flag.  It should probably be on close event if the activex controls run after opening/interacting with workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes I have had to deal with this issue myself. Since these components run AFTER the workbook is opened (and after your `Workbook_Open()` event), you need to run your code *when you're closing your workbook*.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Should be placed in the `ThisWorkbook` code module.

---

To avoid accidentally **not saving** the workbook when you *actually* update it, you could try setting your own global variable flag - which should be located in a standard module and have the `Public` scope. Afterwards, you can use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event to set this flag when you actually change any content within the workbook:

### Standard Module: Add Pub Flag

```
Public bPromptSave as Boolean
```

### Workbook Module: Event Handlers

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    bPromptSave = True

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    if not bPromptSave then ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```